# Pentaho Reporting Ouput component using PDI is giving an error

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using PDI by passing the parameter to prpt using pentaho reporting output component.

However when I try to run the transformation it giving an error as below.
Please help me out in this.

```
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - There was an unexpected error processing report 'C:\Users\ramcharan.gottipati\Desktop\Task' to produce file 'C:\Users\ramcharan.gottipati\Task.CSV' with processor: CSV.
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Failed to open URL connection
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - 
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:317)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processRow(PentahoReportingOutput.java:126)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceLoadingException: Failed to open URL connection
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceData.getResourceAsStream(URLResourceData.java:153)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.AbstractResourceData.getResource(AbstractResourceData.java:83)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader.loadBundle(ZipResourceBundleLoader.java:71)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.loadResourceBundle(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:321)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.loadResourceBundle(ResourceManager.java:248)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.load(ResourceManager.java:264)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:362)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:334)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:200)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.loadMasterReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:164)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:176)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  ... 3 more
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ramcharan.gottipati\Desktop\Task (The system cannot find the file specified)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceData.getResourceAsStream(URLResourceData.java:147)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  ... 13 more
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - tr_Pentaho_reporting_output_8.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2018/09/25 13:48:01 - tr_Pentaho_reporting_output_8.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/09/25 13:48:02 - tr_Pentaho_reporting_output_8.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/09/25 13:48:02 - tr_Pentaho_reporting_output_8.0 - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2018/09/25 13:48:02 - tr_Pentaho_reporting_output_8.0 - Transformation is killing the other steps!
2018/09/25 13:48:56 - Spoon - Save as...
2018/09/25 13:49:08 - Spoon - Using legacy execution engine
2018/09/25 13:49:08 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2018/09/25 13:49:08 - Spoon - Launching transformation [tr_PRO]...
2018/09/25 13:49:08 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2018/09/25 13:49:09 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
```

I tried using PDI V8.0 and PR V8.0. Kindly let me know if I need to add any plugins or any modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured to open 'C:\Users\ramcharan.gottipati\Desktop\Task' as a file, while I asume you should provide a file name.

[here](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Reporting+Output) field is 'Report definition file' should be like
"C:\Users\ramcharan.gottipati\Desktop\Task.prpt"
If you have to specify for field 
'Output file' path to result pdf, like:
"C:\Users\ramcharan.gottipati\Desktop\Task.pdf"

What happens during execution? PDI will use input stream of data for pentaho report processor. Report (prpt) already should be configured to use proper input fields that match field names in input stream in kettle. Names and data types must match or you could get error to process report.
If all is ok, using this step is similar to run pentaho reporting engine using kettle input. Any can run pentaho reporting engine even without kettle at all.

Hope it helps.